# Internet Access to lambda function without NAT

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-aurora

I have a AWS Aurora db in vpc in private subnet.
From Aurora, we need to execute lambda which will connect to pinpoint to send sms.
Lambda function needs access to internet. How to provide internet to vpc without using nat

Comment: whats the problem using NAT ? There is no endpoint for Pinpoint like S3/DynanoDB.

Comment: One problem is cost. When using a serverless stack, it's possible for costs to be basically 0 at low to moderate usage. Once you need a NAT, you're looking at a minimum of $30/month, regardless of how low your usage is.

Comment: Note that if cost is, in fact, the issue, you can use a NAT Instance (docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_NAT_Instance.html) instead of a NAT Gateway, whose fixed costs can theoretically go as low as $4-7/month.

Comment: I'm with this...It kinda flys in the face of serverless computing and "pay-as-you-go" models if you need to have a persistent NAT gateway. Surely the boffins at AWS can dynamically assign an IG on function execution?? I'm almost sure that everyone would pay the tariff on usage if it matched the time used.

Answer (score 3):

As per the AWS docs, if your Lambda function is in a Private Subnet in a VPC, and needs internet access, you need a NAT gateway.

See: [Grant Internet Access to a VPC Lambda Function](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/internet-access-lambda-function/)

Comment: Does that apply to _private_ subnets only or to _public_ subnets, too ?

Comment: My lambda is in a public subnet and still cannot access the internet. What can I do ? the public subnet is connected to internet gateway already